# `go`'s in stored procedures in Sybase 16

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have the following stored procedure in Sybase 16,

```
create or replace procedure ... as
...
drop table tempdb..koppelingen
go
declare 
    vre_cursor cursor  for
...
```

Then I see: `declare cursor must be the only statement in a query batch`.

If I skip the `go`, I can create the stored procedure.

If I execute the code of the stored procedure by hand by selecting it and execute, I have to use the `go`.

So what happens in a stored procedure? Does it insert the `go`'s by itself? But then I do not understand the error message of `declare cursor` above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go` is **not** an ASE command.

`go` is a client-side command that tells the client application (eg, `isql`) that a batch of SQL can now be sent to ASE. In the case of the `create or replace procedure ...` the `go` tells the client application (eg, `isql`) that you've completed the stored proc definition and it can now be submitted to ASE for parsing & compiling.

`declare cursor` must be in a batch of SQL by itself (ie, `declare ...\ngo`) if being run from a client application (eg, `isql`); when inside a stored proc the `declare cursor` command can be grouped with other follow-on commands (eg, `open`, `fetch`).